# "cmp -s file1 file2" doesn't produce any output

Tags: files, file-comparison

```
$ cmp -s file1 file2
```

The above command doesn't return anything for the following cases:

- Case 1: both files (file1 and file2) are different;
- Case 2: both files (file1 and file2) are same.

I tried all the above cases, but my unix system is insensitive.

Answer (score 6):

`-s` is for *silent*, it's to tell `cmp` not to output anything¹ but only to reflect whether the files are identical or not in its exit status so that it can be used for instance in an `if` shell statement:

```
if cmp -s file1 file2; then
  echo same
else
  echo differ or error
fi
```

Or:

```
cmp -s file1 file2 && rm file2
```

If you want it to output something, remove the `-s`. Then `cmp` will output a message when the files differ stating where they start to differ.

---

<sup>¹ except with some implementations for error messages when files can't be opened, not when they differ.</sup>

Comment: I got understood. I am new to Unix, I never went to shell programming learning till now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would question your case 1. If cmp doesn't return anything then the files likely are identical. Try `diff file1 file` and `sum file1 file2` to confirm. Is it possible that the differences are in non-printable characters?